# Multiple lines of text in one listview row?

Tags: java, android, listview, layout

I would like to be able to display two lines of text per row in my listview.
[image]

Under each of those titles, I would like to display another line of text for the date and author name.

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    titleArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    titleArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
        R.id.itemName, titleArray);

}

public void getThreads() throws IOException {
    Thread getThreadsThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(Constants.FORUM).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Elements threads = doc.select(".topic_title");
                for (Element thread : threads) {
                    threadTitle = thread.text();
                    titleArray.add(threadTitle);
                }
        } 
    };
    getThreadsThread.start();
    try {
        getThreadsThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

final Handler mHandler = new Handler(){ 
    public void handleMessage (Message  msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setListAdapter(titleArrayAdapter);
                }
            });
            break;
        }
    } 
};
```

How would you recommend I add another line to the row? For now I would just like to add "Author" and "Date" to the second line, I just need a place holder until I have the code to parse out the corresponding fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you recommend I add another line to the row?

Add a second `TextView` to `res/layout/list_item.xml`, sized and positioned wherever you want it.

In addition, you will need to subclass `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView()`. `ArrayAdapter` only knows how to handle one `TextView` per row -- if you want more than that, you need to handle the rest yourself.

Comment: Oh, well that seems much simpler than I was expecting. Could you explain what you mean by subclass arrayAdapter?

Comment: @r2DoesInc: "Could you explain what you mean by subclass arrayAdapter?" -- um, I mean, create a subclass of `ArrayAdapter`. You know, `class MyFunkyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModelClassThatProbablyIsNoLongerAString>`. [Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android) that goes into more detail.

Comment: Can you please help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982838/how-to-add-new-list-to-listview

Answer (score 2):

Like this [basic example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)?

Comment: I dont think that is applicable to a listview, at least not as far as my basic java skills allow me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a Custom ListAdapter extending the BaseAdapter.

Store your data in a ArrayList and make a new GetView() handling the data in the XML-Layout.